# How do I structure my React Component? (Too bloated)

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a card game and I have a parent component which holds all my methods. The methods are my "logic" and it determines how to set the randomly generated hand  according to 'house-way'. Think of house-way as a set of rules on how to play a certain hand. 
I'm having a problem with how to structure my components. I've heard that you should keep your components small and my component is already 300 lines long.

Any advice on how to restructure this? I've tried putting methods on a different file and importing them, but I had trouble when it comes to setting state. In other words, 'this.setState()' throws an error unless it is a method of a class.

the code is a mess, but I basically need help with how to make my component less bloated.

```
export default class Layout extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
     console.log("starting up");
     super(props);
     //each hand holds a randomly generated tile object from { tilesSet }
     this.state = {
      //needs empty spots for when (mounting) <Hands hand1={this.state.hand[0].img} /> else error since hand[0] doesnt exist.
      hand: ["", "", "", ""],
      cards: false,
      pairName: '',
      rule: '',
      show: false,
      history: [],
      test: 'test'
    };
    //binding in the constructor is recommended for performance.
    this.handleToggle = this.handleToggle.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleHW = this.handleHW.bind(this);
    this.assignHands = this.assignHands.bind(this);
    this.checkPair = this.checkPair.bind(this);
    this.checkTeenDey = this.checkTeenDey.bind(this);
    this.hiLowMiddle = this.hiLowMiddle.bind(this);
    this.compare = this.compare.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }


    //n = pairTL, n2 = otherTL
    split(n, n2){
    //Gee Joon
    if (n[0].pair === 1) {
      let combo1 = baccaratCount(n2[0], n[0]);
      let combo2 = baccaratCount(n2[1], n[1]);
      //if it meets the split requirements...
      if((combo1 >= 7 && combo2 >= 9) || (combo1 >= 9 && combo2 >= 7)){
        console.log('got em', combo1, combo2);
        return true;
      } 
      else {

        return true;
      }
    //Teen/Dey
    // } else if(high[0].val === 2) {
    //   var combo1 = baccaratCount(high[0].val, low[0].val);
    //   var combo2 = baccaratCount(high[0].val, low[1].val);
    //   //checks if any of the tiles are 7,8, or 9. for 9 gong and wong.
    //   var check7_9 = low[0].val >= 7 && low[0].val <= 9;
    //   var check7_9_2 = low[1].val >= 7 && low[1].val <= 9;
    //   //regular 6-8 split rule.
    //   if((combo1 >= 6 && combo2 >= 8) || (combo1 >= 8 && combo2 >= 6)){
    //     moveTiles("split");
    //     return true;
    //     //we might have 7,8,9 with T/D. (with 8 and 9, it turns to 0 and 1, so we need this part.)
    //   } else if (check7_9 === true || check7_9_2 === true){
    //     //if both are 7,8, or 9
    //     if (check7_9 === check7_9_2){
    //       moveTiles("split");
    //       return true;
    //       //only if 1..
    //     } else if (check7_9 === true && check7_9_2 === false){
    //       if (low[1].val >= 3 && low[1].val <=6){
    //         moveTiles("split");
    //         return true;
    //       } else {
    //         moveTiles();
    //         return true;
    //       }
    //       //if other one...
    //     } else{
    //       if (low[0].val >= 3 && low[0].val <=6){
    //         moveTiles("split");
    //         return true;
    //       } else {
    //         moveTiles();
    //         return true;
    //       }
    //     }
    //   //does not split.
    //   } else {
    //     moveTiles();
    //     return;
    // }
    // } else {
    //   // all other pairs. split pairs are in one array with a length of 2. ex: [7, 9]
    //   var combo1 = baccaratCount(high[0].val, low[0].val);
    //   var combo2 = baccaratCount(high[0].val, low[1].val);
    //   if(combo1 >= high[0].split[0] && combo2 >= high[0].split[0]){
    //     moveTiles("split");
    //   } else {
    //     moveTiles();
    //   }
    //   return true;
    // }
    }
    }

    //checks for pairs. takes an array as arg
    checkPair(hand){
    for(let i = 0; i < hand.length; i++) {
      for (let ii = 0; ii < hand.length; ii++) {
        // if there is a pair and it is not comparing to itself.
        if (hand[i].pair === hand[ii].pair && i !== ii) {
          let pairTL = hand.filter((x) => x.rank === hand[i].rank); //array of the pair tiles
          let otherTL = hand.filter((x) => x.rank !== hand[i].rank); // array of the other 2 tiles. use these two to move tiles accordingly
          //if we split this pair...
          if (hand[i].split !== false) {
            //returns true if it split..
            if(this.split(pairTL, otherTL)) {
              let copyArr = [pairTL[0], otherTL[0], pairTL[1], otherTL[1]];
              this.setState(() => ({hand: copyArr}));
            }
            else {
              let copyArr = otherTL.concat(pairTL);
              this.setState(() => ({hand: copyArr}));
              return true;
            }
          }
          //don't split
          else {
            let copyArr = otherTL.concat(pairTL); //concats the two small arrays together and renders.
            this.setState(() => ({hand: copyArr, pairName: pairTL[0].name, rule: 'Don\'t Split'}))
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return false; // no pairs
    }

    //will not execute if there is a pair...(checkPair returns true)
    checkTeenDey(hand){
    //true if we have teen or dey
    let teenDey = hand.find((el) => el.val === 2) !== undefined;
    //if true...
    if(teenDey){
      let tile = hand.find((el) => el.val === 2); // teen/ dey object
      let tempArr = hand.filter((el) => el.name !== tile.name); //new arr without marked teen/dey. arr.length = 3
      let secondTeenDey = tempArr.find((el) => el.val === 2); //second teen/dey (not pair)
      let seven = tempArr.find((el) => el.val === 7);
      let eight = tempArr.find((el) => el.val === 8);
      let nine = tempArr.find((el) => el.val === 9);
      //if there is a second teen/dey
      if (secondTeenDey){
        let twoArr = tempArr.filter((el) => el.name !== secondTeenDey.name);
        console.log(tile, secondTeenDey, twoArr);
        return true;
      }
      //look for 7,8,9
      else if (seven){
        console.log (seven);
        return true;   
      }
      else if(eight){
        return true;
      }
      else if(nine){
        return true;
      }
    }

    // no teen or dey...
    else{
      return false;
    }
  }

    //point system used for sort()
    compare(a,b){
    let comparison = 0;//no change
    if(a.realValue < b.realValue){
      comparison = -1;//a comes before b
    }
    else if(a.realValue > b.realValue){
      comparison = 1;//b comes before a
    }
    return comparison;
    }

    //will not execute if there is a teen dey...
    hiLowMiddle(hand){
    //makes a new copy of hand and sorts it using sort()'s point system.
    let sortedArr = hand.slice().sort(this.compare); //slice used, else mutates hand.
    let tempHair = [sortedArr[0], sortedArr[3]];
    let tempBack = [sortedArr[1], sortedArr[2]];
    let hiLow = tempHair.concat(tempBack); //newly sorted arr
    this.setState(() => ({hand: hiLow, rule: 'Hi-Low-Middle'}));
    }

    //generates new hand and updates them to state.
    assignHands() {
    let tempArr = [0, 0, 0, 0]; //filler array
    let testArr = tilesSet.slice(); //filler array. tilesSet is untouched
    //loops through and assigns random tile from deck
    let newArr = tempArr.map((x) => {
      let counter = Math.floor(Math.random()* (testArr.length - 1));
      //used to hold the selected obj. needed since splice changes arr.length and we splice/display the different indexes.
      let dummyArr = testArr[counter];
      testArr.splice(counter, 1);
      return dummyArr;
      })
      //updates state
      this.setState({hand: [newArr[0], newArr[1], newArr[2], newArr[3]], show: true, history: [...this.state.history, [...newArr]]})
  }

      handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    }

    //toggle effect.
    handleToggle = () => {
    this.setState(() => ({cards: !this.state.cards}));
    }

    handleClick = () => {
    assignHands(tilesSet);  
    //works, but not 100% properly. the changes are one step behind. fix async.
    //check to see the history length. max set @ 20
    if(this.state.history.length >= 10){
      let temp = this.state.history.slice();
      temp.shift();
      this.setState(() => ({history: temp}))
    }
    }

    //House Way
    handleHW(){
    if(!this.checkPair(this.state.hand)){
      if(!this.checkTeenDey(this.state.hand)){
        this.hiLowMiddle(this.state.hand);
      }
    }
    }

    render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.show ? <h1>{baccaratCount(this.state.hand[0], this.state.hand[1]) + '/' + baccaratCount(this.state.hand[2], this.state.hand[3])}</h1> : <h1>Press New Hand to Start</h1>}

        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            <input type='text'/>
          </label>
          <button>submit</button>
        </form>

        <Input test={this.state.test}/>

        <Hands 
          cards={this.state.cards}
          hand1={this.state.hand[0].img}
          hand2={this.state.hand[1].img}
          hand3={this.state.hand[2].img}
          hand4={this.state.hand[3].img} 
        />

        <Buttons 
          type="button" 
          className="btn btn-dark" 
          handleClick={this.handleClick} 
          handleHW={this.handleHW}
          hand={this.state.hand}
        />

        <h2>Value of tiles: {this.state.hand[0].val ? this.state.hand[0].val : "0"} - {this.state.hand[1].val ? this.state.hand[1].val : "0"} - {this.state.hand[2].val ? this.state.hand[2].val : "0"} - {this.state.hand[3].val ? this.state.hand[3].val : "0"}</h2>
        <h2>Pair Name: {this.state.pairName}</h2>
        <h2>Rule: {this.state.rule}</h2>
        <h2>
          History: <div>{this.state.history.map((el) => <li key={Math.random()}>{el.map((ele) => ele.name+ '--')}</li>)}</div>
          </h2>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Since the code is workable, this is a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/